# How to assign Label for dynamically generated DropDownlist?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, label

How do I generate lable text for dynamically generated dropdownlist.
Here is the code:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCityName" runat="server" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="City" class="ddlClone"></asp:DropDownList>
         <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Dropdown" />
    </div>
    <div id="target">
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnClone').click(function () {
        var original = $('select.ddlClone:eq(0)');
        var allSelects = $('select.ddlClone');
        var clone = original.clone();

        $('option', clone).filter(function (i) {
            return allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
        }).remove();        
        $('#target').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');
    });
</script>
```

Everytime the dropdownlist gets generated,I want to display a Label text namely 'category' for it. 
I mean-->

**Category: "Here is my dynamically generated dropdownlist control"**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following:

```
$('#target').append($('<span>').text('Category: '));
$('#target').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');
```

This will insert a new element to the target element! modify as you want it!